# ifup eth0 already configured

Tags: ethernet, buildroot, busybox

I'm building an operating system for my device with `buildroot-2017.08`. The operating system that I got started successfully on my device except one big problem:I have no ipv4 address for eth0.

I have an initial script that configures all interfaces that I have. When started it runs the code: 
    `ifup -a`.
I've checked that the script really runs at the start of the system and checked the output of `ifup`. And I get the message:"Interface eth0 already configured". Just after the boot... Who might have configured this interface? I'm stuck. So it doesn't assign the ip address cause it's already configured...

This is my `/etc/network/interfaces file`

```
    # /etc/network/interfaces -- configuration file for ifup(8), ifdown(8)

    # The loopback interface
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    # Wired or wireless interfaces
    auto eth0
    # iface eth0 inet dhcp
    iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.136
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.2

    auto can0
    iface can0 inet manual
    #pre-up ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 125000 listen-only off
        pre-up ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 125000 triple-sampling on
        up ifconfig $IFACE up
        down ifconfig $IFACE down
```

Can somebody give me a clue of what is going on? Maybe I missed some important settings in `make-menuconfig` or anywhere else. Thank you in advance!

Comment: First of all, Buildroot 2017.08 is really old and no longer supported, please use 2019.08 instead.

Secondly, have you disabled the existing Buildroot logic in /etc/init.d/S40network which runs ifup -a?

Maybe try again with 2019.08 and describe in more details what exactly you are doing / changing.